# Is it possible to install packages on the host OS on a Azure Web App (Linux)

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've built a Python Web App using Django and I'm currently trying to implement SSO.

When running the project locally it works fine because I've installed the necessary packages using `brew install libxml2 libxmlsec1`. When I deploy the project to Azure my requirements.txt can't be installed because the underlying dependencies are not installed on the Azure container.

In an attempt to fix this I've added a prebuild.sh script to run before deployment.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install gcc
sudo apt-get -y install pkg-config
sudo apt-get -y install libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libxmlsec1-openssl
sudo apt-get -y install xmlsec1
```

This doesn't work. In the logs I can see: `sudo command not found`.
I've also tried to run it with `su -c` and with `su -` on the first line.
If I don't use `sudo / su -c / su -`at all, an insufficient privileges error will show.

When installing the packages manually via the SSH client everything will get installed correctly. The only problem with that is that once I exit the session, the changes aren't saved.

Does anyone have an idea how to install the necessary dependencies on Azure?

Comment: What flavor of Azure App Service are you running? I suggest you switch to using a containers.

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΜανωλακος I'm using the Linux Web App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the runtime that Azure provides is the built-in image for general purposes. It maybe cannot match your needs. Just like the situation you met that it does not contain the dependencies you need.

At this time, you need to create the runtime yourself for your special purpose, it means you need to create the [custom image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-docker). For the custom image, it can contain all the things your application need. It means the dependencies, also means the Django and your SSO application. When the custom image can run fine as your wish locally, then you can deploy it to Azure Web app for Container and do not need to deploy the code anymore.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the usage of custom containers but I guess I don't have another option now. Thank you for the explanation.