# Python Package which is installed via SSH gets removed when azure app restarts

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have uploaded Django app on azure server web app using Zip Deploy with FTP. After deploying it gives error that "**sndlibrary not found**" so i need to go to ssh and install it manually by using command `apt update && apt-get -y install libsndfile1-dev`.So The problem is that whenever the app(container) gets restarted it again shows the same error and i again need to install the package from ssh.The package does not persist on restart.So is there any way to persist the package on app restart?

I have also tried using startup.sh script on the wwwroot path but when run it shows error that "**could not locate the package**".

**startup.sh :**
[image: Startup File]

**Getting This Error :**
[image: Error Could not locate package]

Comment: You had the right idea with using a startup script, to me the real question should be about your "could not locate the package" maybe show us this script ?. An even better way would be to install the package during the build step of the container, can you edit the Dockerfile ?

Comment: I have following command in the startup script.
`apt update && apt-get -y install libsndfile1-dev`
and i don't have any idea about editing the dockerfile,it will be great if you can help

Comment: Can you show us the full script and output ? You can also add this `cat /etc/apt/source?.list` to your script just before `apt update && ...` and show us the ouput too ?

Comment: I have updated the question and added both images ,please check

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to install packages on the host OS on a Azure Web App (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62405392/is-it-possible-to-install-packages-on-the-host-os-on-a-azure-web-app-linux) also see [Azure Linux App Service : Installing packages after deploy from Devops pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70807360/azure-linux-app-service-installing-packages-after-deploy-from-devops-pipeline) (you can create a [custom startup script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/configure-python-web-app-on-app-service)).

Answer (score 0):

Every time you restart the container, if the image is rebuilt, the packages are installed from your `requirements.txt` file. What you have to do is simply adding it to your `requirements.txt` file. You can do that either manually, or with the command `pip freeze`.

If you're using docker the command is

```
docker exec <container_name> pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Otherwise if you are inside the runtime environment (Azure VM or docker container) just `pip freeze > requirements.txt` will do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already have requirements.txt file and all the packages in it are installed successfully  but this package can not be installed with the pip so i have to install it manually via ssh.

Comment: Then you have to write a startup script

Answer (score 0):

You get the `could not locate the package` error when trying to install your package because `apt-get update` wasn't successful: `invalid operation update`. I'm not familiar with azure web app service but the problem might come from either:

- You running `*apt* update` and then `*apt-get* install` which should be fixed by using `apt` or `apt-get` for both commands.
- Azure preventing you from running `apt update`
- An issue with apt. Maybe check that the user running startup.sh has the right permissions ?